# TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): get_absolute_url

Tags: python, django

I've been unable to troubleshoot this problem from other questions posted. I've been following a bookstore on a Django tutorial.

Below is my models.py code.

```
import uuid 
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='covers/', blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})

    class Meta:

        permissions = [
            ('special_status', 'Can read all books'),
        ]

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('book_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Review(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        Book,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reviews',
    )
    review = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review
```

I have tried using "Modelform" instead of "Model" but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Methods like `get_absolute_url` and `__str__` should be defined at the level of the `Book` class, not in the `Meta` class, so:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # …
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book_detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})

    class Meta:

        permissions = [
            ('special_status', 'Can read all books'),
        ]

        # def __str__(self):
        #    return self.title
        
        # def get_absolute_url(self):
        #    return reverse('book_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

strictly speaking you can implement a `__str__` method in the `Meta`, but this is not used for basic interactions, and the `Meta` class is normally used to inspect the model.